# Is there qt5-widget-factory just like gtk3-widget-factory?

Tags: qt5

There is a very useful tool named gtk3-widget-factory in gtk3-devel package.
Is there similar tool in Qt5 ?

Comment: qt has its forum here: http://forum.qt.io/ You may get guidance there.

Comment: As help from https://forum.qt.io/topic/98048/is-there-qt5-widget-factory-just-like-gtk3-widget-factory/2 AND https://forum.qt.io/topic/105986/is-there-tools-based-qt5-just-like-gtk3-widget-factory/3 . https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-widgets.html is the best choice at the moment.

Comment: If you expand on your comment a little, you could post an answer! Please ping me if you do. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ask the same question in Qt Forum. The experts recommend the "Qt Widgets Examples". It is the best choice for now. 
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-widgets.html